# Using a modal with flip boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to apply a modal to a button on the back side of a flip box and the trouble I'm having is that when I flip from front to back the modal automatically opens up, AND, it is INSIDE the flip box, not taking up the full page. Here is the example I have uploaded. Note that I have not applied the modal to boxes 2,3 & 4.

https://theinkwell.net/flipModalTest.html

I am using the code from W3Schools and it works fine inside its own div, but not from within the flip box itself. I am wanting to have the modal open up as a full page modal.

JS

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("modalBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<section class="sec6">
    <h2>Some common reasons for counselling</h2>
    <div class="bigbox">
        <div class="bigbox-two">
        <p class="instruction">Click on the box to see more...</p>

        <div class="col-1">   
            <div class="container">                
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="front">
                        <!-- front content -->
                        <p>anxiety</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <!-- back content -->                        
                        <p>Occasional anxiety is a normal part of life.     But anxiety disorders 
involve more than temporary worry or fear.</p>
                    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
                    <p><button class="modalBtn">Read more...</button></p>

                        <!-- ======================== MODAL For Box ONE ====================== -->           


                        <!-- The Modal -->
                        <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                          <!-- Modal content -->
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <span class="close">&times;</span>
                              <h2>Modal Header</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                              <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
                              <p>Some other text...</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                              <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                         <!-- =================== END MODAL for Box ONE ======================= -->
                </div>
            </div><!-- end card -->

        </div>
    </div> <!-- end col-1 -->
```

CSS

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; /* Fade in the background */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
     color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
 }

 .close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
    from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0} 
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}
```

Comment: Better chances of getting help if the code was in a snippet that people can run.

Comment: Thank you MarsAndBack. I will look to do that.